# mongostat query column vs active read(ar) column interpretation

Tags: mongodb

```
insert query update delete getmore command % dirty % used flushes       vsize     res qr|qw ar|aw netIn netOut conn     time   
1405   622     *0     *0       0     1|0     6.8   70.0       0    2.3G    2.1G   0|0   1|0    2m   205k   12 18:35:49
1895   978     *0     *0       0     1|0     6.9   70.3       0    2.3G    2.1G   0|0   1|0    3m   353k   12 18:35:50
1951   764     *0     *0       0     3|0     7.1   70.4       0    2.3G    2.1G   0|0   1|0    3m   228k   12 18:35:51
```

why there is difference between the query operation number which is in hundred while my active read(ar) metrics remains only one.

I am running findone queries so each connection only got single query read operation.
how to interpret mongostat?

Answer (score 1):

From [mongostat](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongostat/):

> **ar** : The number of active clients performing read operations.

It's active read**ers**, not active reads.

Comment: .Ok. So one active reader is doing 622 read operations? I am quoting first row of mongostat output. If not then why there is large difference between the number of query operation done per second and the the number of active readers.